# TLSOption CipherSuites does not work on Istio Ingress Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have deployed a CipherSuite on an Istio Ingress Gateway object:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hello-istio-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway  # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "*"
    port:
      name: https-wildcard
      number: 444
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      cipherSuites: "[ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256]"
```

But from kubectl I get the error

```
admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: error decoding configuration: YAML decoding error:
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []json.RawMessage
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my manifest?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
rforberger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"` chars from the `cipherSuites`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hello-istio-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway  # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - "*"
    port:
      name: https-wildcard
      number: 444
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      cipherSuites: [ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256]
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f gateway.yaml
gateway.networking.istio.io/hello-istio-gateway created
```

Comment: cipherSuites: [ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256] is not working for me. changing '|' to ',' is working.